# Coldfusion onRequestStart show some error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, application.cfc

I try to write a onRequestStart function in application.cfc and code is

```
 function onRequestStart(requestname){ 
    if(!structKeyExists(session, "UserId") or !structKeyExists(session, "LoggedIn") ){
        if(!(find("login",requestname) > 0 or find("signup",requestname) > 0)){
           location("/mobile/index.cfm",false);
        }
    }else{
            location("/mobile/dashbord.cfm",false);
    }
}
```

the above code if condition is working ,after login the else condition will show **This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.** this error. why show this error , i am new in coldfusion please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This is to be expected. The onRequest will fire on every request. When you request dashboard.cfm it will run this code again, once again going into the else statement and redirecting. This results in an infinite loop.

Comment: @haxtbh  thanks, i will check the session only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to locate the dashbord from dashbord page, Incase you are hitting the page like this and it will show the issue of **redirected you too many times** , so you need to put some condition in else statement like below,

```
!find("dashbord",requestname) > 0
```